# Javascript-How to use push method inside of another function to push string to an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript

**Hi there, brand new developer (obviously) and I'm dealing with some issues with trying to modify an existing array in an object without changing the existing array.**

My instructions:

// The burrito class should have a method named `addTopping`. 
// This method should accept one argument, a String. 
// The method should add a topping to the list of toppings held in state.

// Call the `addTopping` method on two burritos, then log the burritos to verify 
// that the proteins have been changed.

**I am having issues with getting the 'addTopping' method to work while using the push method. I know I am doing something wrong and I'm sure it is quite obvious. Thank you for your time :).**

My code:

```
class Burrito {
  constructor(protein, base, toppings) {
    this.protein = protein;
    this.base = base;
    this.toppings = toppings;
  }
  
changeProtein() {
  this.protein = "chicken";
}

  addTopping() {
    this.toppings = "pico de gallo";
  }
};

var burrito1 = new Burrito ("soyrizo", "white rice", ["lettuce", "sour cream", "guacamole"]);
var burrito2 = new Burrito ("shrimp", "brown rice", ["cilantro", "lettuce", "salsa", "cheese"]);
var burrito3 = new Burrito ("steak", "white rice", ["green chile", "cheese"]);

burrito1.changeProtein();
console.log(burrito1);

var addToppings = ["lettuce", "pico de gallo"];

addTopping() {
  this.toppings = toppings.push(addToppings);
}
```

Thanks again :)

Comment: use the function keyword to declare a function

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: *"then log the burritos to verify that the proteins have been changed."* There is no information on how adding a topping changes the proteins. I have the impression some information is missing: shouldn't `proteins` be a *number*? Do you have the number of proteins for each unit of topping? Is it not the purpose to *add* the number of proteins to a total as each topping is added? ... In short: something is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this

```
class Burrito {
  constructor(protein, base, toppings) {
    this.protein = protein;
    this.base = base;
    this.toppings = toppings;
  }
  
  changeProtein() {
     this.protein = "chicken";
  }

  addTopping(topping) {
    this.toppings.push(topping) ;
  }
};

/* snip */

burrito3.addTopping("lettuce")

/* or */
var addToppings = ["lettuce", "pico de gallo"];
toppings.forEach(topping => burrito3.addTopping(topping))
```

`push` adds 1 item onto an array.  to add an array on you need to use a differnet method like `concat`

MDN  is apretty good resource

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed the first option, you're a lifesaver. Thanks for the resources :).